# Absolute positioned div not display full content when the content extends beyond the browser height

Tags: css, html, overflow, positioning, css-position

So, my issue right now is that I have a wrapper div with overflow: hidden and a min-height: 100% so that it stays the height of the browser window.

However, this causes issues when I have a huge population of content on the sidebar (shown in the linked image)

http://d.pr/2jVn

If I remove the overflow: hidden from the wrapper div then it'll just look funky.

What I need to know is how to keep my content displaying without it disappearing.

Comment: Show some actual code, or you get the stock answer: don't use `position: absolute` - instead move it to where it is using another method. Or just apply `overflow-y: auto` to the sidebar if you want it to scroll.

Comment: Put a working example on jsfiddle.net so we can take a look.  You need to put some efforts in your questions to get answers

Answer (score 1):

Add max-height:100% and overflow: auto at your div. i am pretty sure this is going to work. But it would be better for us if you provided some code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this:

```
#yourDiv {
    min-height:100%;
}
```